# How to assign a value on this 3x3 square (kare)?

Tags: java, arrays, object, setter, getter

I am trying to create a 3x3 square slots that I can play with it, assign value, value exchange...

This `esas` variable is the number I want to assign to slots. I tried on this longer syntax put 5 to slot 0, however when I try to `getEsas` again it becomes zero.

Is there a way to do this correct, or another method I can use?

```
package abc;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sirala {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kare k1=new Kare();
        int aa;
        k1.siram(0).setEsas(5);
        System.out.println(k1.siram(0).getEsas());
    }

    public static int kisa (int ai) {
        Kare k2=new Kare();
        return k2.siram(ai).getA();
    }
}
```

```
public class Kare extends Object {

    private int a;
    int x=1;
    int y=1;
    private int esas;

    Kare() {}

    Kare(int x,int y) {
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
      a = (x-3+3*y);
    }

    public int getA() {return a;}

    public void setA (int a) {this.a=a;}

    public int getEsas() {return esas;}

    public void setEsas(int esas) {this.esas=esas;}

    public Kare siram (int n1){

        boolean exa=(x==3);
        boolean eya=(y==3);
        Kare[] arr=new Kare[9];

        for (int i=0;i<9;i++) {
            arr[i]=new Kare(x,y);
            if (!exa) {x++;}
            else {
                if (!eya) {x=1;y++;}
                else {x=3;y=3;}
            }
        }
        return arr[n1];
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened to indentation?

Comment: Sorry, i m new on java and new here.. I ll do better next time

Comment: You can [edit] your question and do better _this_ time.

Comment: I m sorry, i ll learn rules here and fix myself.. Thanks for warn me @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that , when you print, you get 0 instead of 5, is not surprising at all.

When you call `k1.siram(0)` first time, you are building an array, populate it, and return the first element of the array.  When you call `k1.siram(0)` the second time, you are building a brand new array, whose first element you return. Calling `k1.siram(0)` multiple times returns a totally different element everytime. What you did was to call the setter on a Kare instance, and then call the getter on a totally different Kare instance. If you want to see value 5 printed, you can store the result of `k1.siram(0)` in a variable, like

```
Kare k_ = k1.siram(0);
k_.setEsas(5);
System.out.println(k_.getEsas());
```

Note that `Kare[] arr` is a local variable, which will only be alive inside the block of `siram` method, during a method call. For the next method call, another array is built. Perhaps you thought that every call would refer to the same array, but this is not the case. If you want your method to refer always to the same array, place this array outside the method body. I also feel that filling the 3X3 matrix should be done in a different class, not in Kare. Perhaps a class called Matrix.

```
public class Matrix {
    public static Kare[][] matrix = new Kare[3][3];
    //matrix is declared 'static' because it is one per application; 
    //you don't want different instances of Matrix, each one with its own  Kare[][] matrix

    //the equivalent of siram()
    public static void fillMatrix() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                matrix[i][j] = new Kare(i,j);
    }

}

public class Sirala {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Matrix.fillMatrix();
        Matrix.matrix[1][2].setEsas(5);
        System.out.println(Matrix.matrix[1][2].getEsas());

        //because matrix field is static, i call it using class name, like Matrix.matrix
        //otherwise, i would have called it   new Matrix().matrix
    }
}
```

I recommend that you translate into English the following terms: Sirala , Kare, siram, kisa ,esas. It will make the code easier to understand.

I also suggest that you take a look at chapters 3 & 4 of the following book - http://www2.nsru.ac.th/tung/java_doc/Core%20Java%20Volume%20I-%20Fundamentals%209th%20Edition-%20Horstmann,%20Cay%20S.%20&%20Cornell,%20Gary_2013.pdf - for a better understanding of the Java fundamentals.